# How do I display selected item on the console

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting values of the selected checkbox on my app. I want to display the items checked by the user to the console.

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
private List<Problems> mDataset;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;
private ProblemListener setProblemListener;
CardView cv;

public void setProblemListener(ProblemListener problemListener){
    this.setProblemListener = problemListener;
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView tvProblems, tvPrice;
    public Button btnProblem;
    Button btnSubmitProblem;
    CheckBox cbProblems;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProblems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProblems);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        btnSubmitProblem = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProblems);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);

       overrideFonts(context, tvProblems);
    }
}
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensedBold.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void add(List<Problems> itemList){
    mDataset = itemList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void remove(Problems item){
    int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public MyAdapter(Context con, List<Problems> myDataset){
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.context = con;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View itemView;
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //Inflating recycle view item layout
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_content, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);

    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //Inflating header view
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_recycler_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
        //Inflating footer view
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.problem_recycler_footer, parent, false);
        return new FooterViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    try {
    if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {

        HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        headerHolder.tvHeader.setText("Please kindly ask the mechanic what the problem is and check them to continue");

    } else {
        if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {

            final FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            footerHolder.btnSubmitProblem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //  footerHolder.cbProblems.setOnClickListener(null);
                   setProblemListener.onProblemSelected(v, mDataset, position);

                }
            });

        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            ItemViewHolder itemView = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

            //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
            itemView.cbProblems.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
            itemView.cbProblems.setChecked(mDataset.get(position-1).isSelected());

            itemView.tvPrice.setText(mDataset.get(position - 1).getPrice());
            itemView.tvProblems.setText(mDataset.get(position - 1).getProblems());


            itemView.cbProblems.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()){
                        mDataset.get(position - 1).setSelected(isChecked);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "postion " + position + "Boolean value " + Boolean.valueOf(isChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size()+2;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if (position == mDataset.size() + 1) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvHeader;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        overrideFonts(context, tvHeader);
    }
}

private class FooterViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    Button btnSubmitProblem;
    CheckBox cbProblems;


    public FooterViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        btnSubmitProblem = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnProblems);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);
    }
}

private class ItemViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvProblems, tvPrice;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProblems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProblems);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cards);

    }
}

private class CheckboxViewHolder extends MyAdapter.ViewHolder {
    public CheckboxViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cbProblems = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbProblems);

    }
}
public interface ProblemListener{
    void onProblemSelected(View view, List<Problems> problem, int position);
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class ProblemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String PROBLEM_URL = MYURL.url + "get-problems";

CardView cardView;
CheckBox breakCheckBox;
private ListView getListValue, listView;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Button btnSubmitProblems;
String problems;
List<Problems> listProblems = new ArrayList<>();
DividerItemDecoration mDividerItemDecoration;
Toolbar toolbar;
private double price = 0.0;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 MyAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_problems);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.problem_recycle_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ProblemsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(ProblemsActivity.this, listProblems);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, PROBLEM_URL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse(response);
            jsonParse.parseJSON();
            listProblems = jsonParse.getProblems();
            mAdapter.add(listProblems);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("Info", "Failed");
            error.printStackTrace();

        }

    });
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(ProblemsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
    mAdapter.setProblemListener(new MyAdapter.ProblemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProblemSelected(View view, List<Problems> problem, int position) {

           selectedProblems = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Problems item: problem)
            {
                if(item.isSelected())
                {
                    selectedProblems.add(item);
                }
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String selectedProblem = gson.toJson(selectedProblems);

            JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse(selectedProblem);
            jsonParse.parseJSON();
            finalSelectedProblems = jsonParse.getProblems();

            sendProblemsToServer(selectedProblems);
    });
}

public void sendProblemsToServer(List<Problems> selectedProblems){

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.logout){

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
        preferences.edit().clear().commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProblemsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class); // Create an Intent
        startActivity(intent); // Move to Verification Activity
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (id == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 }
```

I am getting the model value instead of the actual value. Is there any way I can just figure this thing out. I am just stuck on this issue spent some hours trying to figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with below lines:

```
        for (Problems p: selectedProblems){
            sb.append(p);
            sb.append("\t");
        }
```

Here, you are append an object of non-string type to string builder. Hence, before appending, the builder converts the Problem to string by calling p.toString method.

You can fix this by overriding the toString method in Problems class as below

```
class Problems {
...
  @Override
  public String toString() {
     //Your custom impementation here...
  }
}
```